# What is the "once" warnings in perl?

Tags: perl, warnings

I have code that has,

```
no warnings 'once';
```

Reading `man warnings` I don't see an occurrence of `/once/` what does this do?

Comment: Specific warnings are listed in perldiag: https://perldoc.pl/perldiag#Name-%22%25s::%25s%22-used-only-once:-possible-typo

Comment: Perl warnings are documented in [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html), accessible via `perldoc perldiag` and `man perldiag`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as you don't have `strict` on, perl allows you to use a variable without declaring it.

```
perl -wE'$foo = 4;'
```

Which outputs,

> Name `main::foo` used only once: possible typo at `-e` line 1.

Note under `strict` this wouldn't even be permitted,

> Global symbol `$foo` requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare `my $foo`?) at -e line 1.

You *can* disable the warning though, without enabling `strict` by doing `no warnings "once";` Though I would suggest strongly **you simply remove the unused code instead of silencing the warning.**

```
perl -wE'no warnings "once"; $foo = 4;'
```

Which both looks ugly and does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

If you run the following you will trigger the warning, plus a little extra explanation:

```
perl -Mdiagnostics -Mwarnings -e '$foo=1'
```

The output will be:

```
Name "main::foo" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1 (#1)
    (W once) Typographical errors often show up as unique variable names.
    If you had a good reason for having a unique name, then just mention it
    again somehow to suppress the message.  The our declaration is
    provided for this purpose.

    NOTE: This warning detects symbols that have been used only once so $c, @c,
    %c, *c, &c, sub c{}, c(), and c (the filehandle or format) are considered
    the same; if a program uses $c only once but also uses any of the others it
```

The warning applies to symbol table entries (not "my" lexical variables).  If you add `-Mstrict` to the above, you'll create a strict violation because your variable violates `strict 'vars'`, which prohibits you using a variable that hasn't been declared, with the exception of package globals referred to by their fully-qualified name.  If you were to pre-declare `$foo` with `our`, the warning goes away:

```
perl -Mdiagnostics -Mwarnings -Mstrict=vars -E 'our $foo=1'
```

This works just fine; it avoids a strict violation, and avoids the "once" warning.   So the purpose of the warning is to alert you to the use of identifiers that are not declared, not using a fully-qualified name, and also only used once.  The objective is to help prevent typos in symbol names, the assumption being that if you use a symbol name only once and have not declared it, it may be a mistake.

Special (punctuation) variables are exempted from this check. You can, therefore, refer to `$_` or `$/` only once and not trigger a warning. Also, `$a` and `$b` are exempt because they are considered special, for use in `sort {$a <=> $b} @list`; in such constructs they may appear only a single time yet it wouldn't be useful to raise a warning for what is fairly typical code.

You can find the 'once' warning listed in the Warnings Hierarchy here: [perldoc warnings](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html#Category-Hierarchy).

A list of all diagnostic blurbs is available in [perldoc perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html).

Comment: David thank you for good explanation -- now I have reason to use **diagnostics** module.

Comment: Interesting, why warning does not appear for `my $x`